# How to mock a keypress in test method?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I wrote a game of life console application and now I'm writing unit tests for it. The game board is rendered in a loop that can be broken with Esc press. I do not know however how to simulate that keypress in my test method for the main application class so my test currently loops indefinitely.

**Application.cs**

```
public class Application
{
    private readonly IGame _game;
    private readonly IBoard _board;
    private readonly IBoardGenerator _boardGenerator;
    private readonly IConsole _console;

    public Application(IGame game, IBoard board, IBoardGenerator boardGenerator, IConsole console)
    {
        _game = game;
        _board = board;
        _boardGenerator = boardGenerator;
        _console = console;
    }
    public void Run()
    {
        void RenderBoard()
        {
            _console.Clear();
            _board.Evolve();
            _board.Print();
            Thread.Sleep(150);
        } 

        LoopUntilButtonPressed(() =>
        { 
            _console.Clear();
            _game.NewGame();
            _game.SetBoard(_board, _boardGenerator);
            LoopUntilButtonPressed(RenderBoard, ConsoleKey.Escape);
        }, ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }

    private void LoopUntilButtonPressed(Action action, ConsoleKey consoleKey)
    {
        do
        {
            while (!_console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
        } while (_console.ReadKey(true) != consoleKey);
    }
```

**ApplicationTests.cs**

```
[TestFixture]
public class ApplicationTests
{
    private Mock<IGame> _fakeGame;
    private Mock<IBoard> _fakeBoard;
    private Mock<IBoardGenerator> _fakeBoardGenerator;
    private Mock<IConsole> _fakeConsole;
    private Application _application;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _fakeGame = new Mock<IGame>();
        _fakeBoard = new Mock<IBoard>();
        _fakeBoardGenerator = new Mock<IBoardGenerator>();
        _fakeConsole = new Mock<IConsole>();
        _application = new Application(_fakeGame.Object, _fakeBoard.Object, _fakeBoardGenerator.Object, _fakeConsole.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Run_MethodCalled_GameCorrectlySet()
    {
        _application.Run();
        _fakeConsole.Setup(c => c.ReadKey(It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(ConsoleKey.Escape);
        _fakeConsole.Setup(c => c.KeyAvailable).Returns(true);

        _fakeGame.Verify(g => g.NewGame(), Times.Once);            
    }
}
```

Comment: just mock the `ReadKey` and `KeyAvailable` members on console abstraction

Comment: Also what is the exit strategy for the code under test. you have an infinite loop and no break. How were you planning on exiting?

Comment: @Nkosi, there is a condition `while (_console.ReadKey(true) != ConsoleKey.Escape);`

Comment: @RomanDoskoch and that is within a `while(true) {...}`

Comment: @Nkosi, yeah, you are right

Comment: refactored as per the edit but `_console.KeyAvailable` evaluates to `false` and `_console.ReadKey(true)` to `0`

Comment: @KarolSkrobot the setup needs to happen before the method under test. you edit shows them after you have already called `Run`

Comment: I would also suggest you setup a sequence for `KeyAvailable` so that a break condition can be invoked when the mocked member are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mock the `ReadKey` and `KeyAvailable` members on the console abstraction.

Ensure the `Setup` happens before the method under test. Which in this case is `Run`. That way the mocks will behave as expected when invoked.

I would also suggest you setup a sequence for `KeyAvailable` so that a break condition can be invoked when the mocked member are used in the `while`.

```
[Test]
public void Run_MethodCalled_GameCorrectlySet() {
    //Arrange        
    _fakeConsole.Setup(_ => _.ReadKey(It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(ConsoleKey.Escape);
    _fakeConsole.SetupSequence(_ => _.KeyAvailable)
        .Returns(false) // will be returned on 1st invocation
        .Returns(true); // will be returned on 2nd invocation to break while

    //Act
    _application.Run();

    //Assert
    _fakeGame.Verify(_ => _.NewGame(), Times.Once);            
}
```